# How to compile multiple files in g++ with extern

Tags: c++, g++, fedora

I'm doing some experiment about extern keywork and currently working on Fedora 19 and g++.
Im trying to compile multiple c++ files and execute the program. Here it compiled successfully. but when try to run it shows `Permission denied` error. I change to permission using `chmod` to 777. but still result is same. then I try to compile and run a simple Hello World program and That works fine. Whats wrong with my program?

test1.h

```
int a=0;
```

test2.h

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern int a;    
void foo()
{
 cout << "This is a test string " << endl;
 cout << a << endl;
}

int main()
{
 foo();
}
```

Here is how I compiled and the execute result of  theTerminal

```
[root@localhost cpp]# g++ test1.h test2.h -o test.o
[root@localhost cpp]# ./test.o
bash: ./test.o: Permission denied
[root@localhost cpp]#
```

Comment: Have you tried to execute chmod a+x command to set access rights?

Comment: I'm not sure but probably it's due the fact `.o` extension is usually used to object files which aren't executables. Then the shell maybe is just preventing it to be executable like it do to a raw binary. Why not just try `-o test` instead of?

Comment: @Dmitry Fucintv  I used `chmod 777 test.o`

Comment: @The Mask: I already tried that. But same result. Next thing is "Hello World" program works for `test.o`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several problems.  If you use the [`file(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) utility to inspect the output file, you'll realize why it can't be executed:

```
$ file test.o
test.o: GCC precompiled header (version 013) for C++
```

Precompiled header files are not valid executable files—they're not valid ELF files and they're not script files with a shbang line, they're just data files that the compiler knows how to read.

Why are you getting a precompiled header file?  Because you're asking g++ to compile header files (`.h` files).  It's really ridiculous to give your C++ source files `.h` extensions, because they're not header files, they're source files.  Give them the proper `.cc` or `.cpp` extensions, and g++ will compile them correctly to an executable.

Secondly, why are you giving the output file the name `test.o`?  `.o` is used for object files (compiled versions of singular source files, not complete executables), but you're asking g++ to compile a full executable.  If you only want to compile and not also link, then pass the `-c` flag, and then manually link the object files together.  Don't name your executables with `.o`.  `test` would be the more proper name for an executable compiled from a source file named `test.cc`, but I'd caution against that and recommend using something else, because `test` is also the name of a [shell builtin function](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins).

Comment: What a nice answer! change *.h to *.cpp. everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

When you compile `.h` files using `g++`, the compiler generates precompiled header files. These are not executable files. They won't run even if you changed their permissions to `777`.

Look for **This program is also useful when precompiling a C header file with a ‘.h’ extension for use in C++ compilations.** at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.3/gcc/Invoking-G_002b_002b.html#Invoking-G_002b_002b.

Try these commands:

```
g++ -o test.o test1.h
file test.o
```

You should get the output

```
test.o: GCC precompiled header (version 014) for C++
```

To create an executable, rename the files to `test1.cc` and `test2.cc`. Then, build the executable from them using

```
g++ -o test test1.cc test2.cc
```

Now, you will be able to execute the program using:

```
./test
```